# Ivy thinks BehaviorSubject's initial value is null

Tags: angular, rxjs

The component looks like this:

```js
mappedChoices$ = new BehaviorSubject<SomeType[]>([]);
```

```html
[choices]="mappedChoices$ | async"
```

Ivy build error:

```
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SomeType[]'.
```

WTF? It's initialized as an empty array.

Comment: could you try `(mappedChoices$ | async)!`? not sure if it works in templates, but it is worths trying

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would propose to use `!` opreator. like this

```
(mappedChoices$ | async)!
```

Answer (score 0):

The `async` pipe transform will convert an `Observable<T>` into `T|null` and will return null until a value is emitted. It can't guarantee that an Observable will emit a value right after the subscription, hence the initial value of `null`.

I guess an override could be added to the async pipe code so that if input is `BehaviorSubject<T>` the output is `T` not `T|null`.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L102

```js
private _latestValue: any = null;

...

transform<T>(obj: Observable<T>|Subscribable<T>|Promise<T>): T|null;
```

Comment: I see.  The parent and child needs to update it's typing to include `null`. 

Not fun at all. This feels like Ivy is raising problems I don't have.

Comment: Well if some programmer forgot to pass a value into an input, then it also would be null. Seems to me that typing inputs as non-nullable is just a wish.

Comment: @s.Lawrenz I guess they could make add an override to the `async` pipe code so if that the input is a `BehaviorSubject<T>` the output is `T` (not `T|null`), otherwise an `Observable<T>` won't guarantee you'll get a value right after the subscription (hence the implicit `null` value).